# workaround for alexa not understanding the word 'postpaid' in my skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Alexa just doesn't understand the word 'postpaid' and I've tried it a million times in my skill. I also tried "Alexa, Simon says postpaid" but it repeats something else other than postpaid, I don't know why. My sample utterance is like this "what is the {type} sales" and the type has custom slot values "postpaid",etc.

I've looked at AMAZON.LITERAL but didn't quite understand it if it will help me in my case. So any workaround will be helpful and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What does Alexa think you said? Maybe you can use that in your intent also. Your code can check for and replace whatever that is to "postpaid".

This is a bit of a hack, but may work for you until Amazon provides us with a way to fine tune input.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa will not always restrict the transcription the options in a slot to the given values, specially if you have a large list of possible values. Either using a list or AMAZON.LITERAL, in this case, your best bet may be to check wether the identified value is in fact one of the values in your list and use it, otherwise, you can use a phonetic matching/similarity algorithm to select the closest value.

Hit me up if you need example code (in Python in my case)

Answer (score 0):

This feels simplistic but have you tried breaking postpaid into two words?

```
{type} == "post paid"
```

Slots can contain multi word utterances.  Perhaps Alexa will recognize the two distinct morphemes.